# android list elements from an array list

Tags: android, list, filter

I have the followig list:

```
List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It contains a list with fruites. How to filter the list after the `first 1 or 2 or three characters` from an element (`startsWith()`) and display the first element from the list after it is filtered?

Can someone please give me an example?

Appreciate!!

Comment: which component you are using? `ListView` or `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: [See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/)

Comment: i am using autocompletetextview and i need ti filter the item object after the first characters

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collection` for this

```
 Collections.sort(item, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is s1 and what is s2? could you give me a concrete example?

Comment: those are the strings from your list. Please take a look at the sources of Collections.sort method if you want to get more details on that